# ActionEvent won't appear

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionevent

I have a problem in my program. Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;`

public class click_rep extends JFrame{`

    public click_rep(){

        super("CLICK");
        final JButton btn1 = new JButton("CLICK HERE");
        final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);
        add(btn1);
        setSize(315,120);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try{
                    String command = e.getActionCommand();
                    if (command.equals(btn1)){
                        label.setText("CLICK");
                        setVisible(true);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] a){
        click_rep cp = new click_rep();
    }

}
```

My problem is that the ActionEvent won't appear. What will I do to make the ActionEvent appear?

Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at this...

```
String command = e.getActionCommand();
if (command.equals(btn1)){
```

`command` is a `String` and `btn1` is a `JButton`, when are they likely to ever be `equal`?

There are a few ways you might fix it, you could, for example, do something like this...

```
if ("CLICK HERE".equals(command)) {
```

Or something like this...

```
if (e.getSource() == btn1) {
```

But I prefer the first one...

But, because the `ActionListener` is an annoymouse listener registered to `btn1`, the source of the event can never be anything other then `btn1`, so you could simply do something like this instead...

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        label.setText("CLICK");
        // Not sure what this is meant for, as the component
        // must already be visible in order for the user to 
        // activate the button...
        setVisible(true); 
    }

});
```